# How to generate a conditional subset?

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes, combinatorics

I want to develop an algorithm to generate a random subset (size $k$) from
$\{1, . . . , n\} $ given that it contains at least one of the
elements in $\{1, . . . , s\}$ ($s,k\ll n$).

This is what I was thinking:

Denote with  $S_1, S_2,..., S_n$  any permutation of $1, 2,..., n$. Let $j=n$ and while $j > n-k-1$, generate a random number $U$ while letting  $i = \lfloor jU\rfloor + 1$.
Swap the values of $S_i$ and $S_j$ and set $ j= j − 1$. 
The random subset is $S_{n-k-1},...S_n$.

However, here I did not implement the fact that at least one of the elements has to be in $\{1,2,..,s\}$. For this, do I just need to add another condition in the while?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I dont get your question fully but here is my suggestion: sample one element from the list {1,....s} and then sample k-1 elements from {1,....n}. As a result, you will have a subset size of K that contains at least one element from {1,...,s}.

Comment: That would not work. Suppose the element sampled from {1,...,s} is 1. and suppose the elements sampled from {1,...n} are {1,8,9,15,3,0,88,14}. By your logic, my random subset should be {1,8,9,15,3,0,88,14,1}. But this is not a subset of {1,...,n}. You would need to check if the element sampled from {1,...,s} is in my other sampled set.

Comment: You can remove the selected element from {1,...,n} and then sample K-1 elements.